# Execute method regularly for a given duration whilst in an asnyc call

Tags: c#, async-await, nonblocking

I have a class with an `int` property that is updated regularly (Currently this isn't set up and the value is updated manually in code with a `Thread.Sleep()` call simulating code running).

I am using events to signal when the value changes and execute some code when this happens.

A simplified version of my class would look like this :

```
public class Base
{
    public event EventHandler CurrentValueUpdated;

    protected virtual void OnCurrentValueUpdated() 
    {
        CurrentValueUpdated?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    private int _currentValue;
    public int CurrentValue 
    {
        get => _currentValue
        set
        {
            _currentValue = value;
            OnCurrentValueUpdated();
        } 
    }

    public Derived(int value)
    {
        CurrentValue = value;
    }
}
```

I have another class which subscribes to the event and looks like the following (Assume here that the subscription is done and the two classes are linked by the event):

```
public class StateCondition
{
    public int SetpointA { get; set; }
    public Derived DerivedInstance { get; set; }

    public StateCondition(int setpointA, Derived derivedInstance) 
    {
        SetpointA = setpointA;
        DerivedInstance = derivedInstance;
    }

    public void OnValueChanged(object source, EventArgs args)
    {
        EvaluateCondition();
    }

    public void EvaluateCondition()
    {
        if (DerivedInstance.CurrentValue == SetpointA)
        {
            Task.Run(async delegate
            {
                await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
                EvaluateConditionDelayed();
            });
        }
    }

    public void EvaluateConditionDelayed()
    {
        if (DerivedInstance.CurrentValue == SetpointA)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am activated")
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I have here is that I need to constantly check the condition for the given time period (Here 5 seconds) before actually "activating" the condition.
Another issue is that if the value changes every 50 ms, will the async-await call happen multiple times ?

So to put it simply, following the above structure:

- How can I regularly check the condition `==` for a given duration ?
- Does having an event being triggered regularly, with this asnc-await, give a method execution following the event triggering ?

Ideally, I would like to have a system that does the following:

- Value updates
- If value checks condition

  - Check condition regularly for a given time period without halting the rest of the code
  - If still true after time period has ended

    - Activate condition
  - Else

    - Cancel activation and prepare for a new value change

Comment: what is the scope of `Derived ` here? is it specific to this interaction? oddly, I'm wondering if one way to do this is to have `Derived` host a `CancellationTokenSource`, and have it *cancel* it when a value gets assigned... then your *awaiting* code can pass the token of the same into `Task.Delay`, and whichever happens first: happens first. You could do the same with an `event` (your `CurrentValueUpdated`) if you want to keep the two things at more of a distance

Comment: No `Derived` is used much more broadly in my overall code. It will eventually interact with numerous other classes and objects...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hacky, but I wonder if you can use the event for this (note: your `CurrentValueUpdated` delegate is **not** currently an `event` - you should fix that first, otherwise you don't have the same threading guarantees):

```cs
using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
EventHandler handler = (s, a) => cts.Cancel();
DerivedInstance.CurrentValueUpdated += handler;
try
{
    await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), cts.Token);
    // if we get here, we probably timed out *without* seeing it change
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{} // this should happen if we see it change
finally
{   // remove the event subscription
    DerivedInstance.CurrentValueUpdated -= handler;
}
EvaluateConditionDelayed(); // check this however we exited
```

Note also that there may be a race condition here if someone changed the value *right after* you have tested it, and before you have subscribed - so you might want to double-check the value *after* subscribing the event.

Comment: Curiosity is making me ask what you mean by "Not currently an event" ? I'm quite a novice with C# honestly and I'm learning as I need so events are rather new to me in the sense that I don't know how to use them correctly.

Comment: Also, I like the idea of the cancellation token which I will look into, but how does this solution verify the `CurrentValue` property during the example 5 seconds ?

Comment: @MaxMichel `public EventHandler CurrentValueUpdated;` is not an event - it is a field that happens to be of type `EventHandler`; `public event EventHandler CurrentValueUpdated;` is an event - this is similar to the difference between fields and automatically implemented properties, but with the added bonus that the compiler ensures that event add/remove hooks are thread-safe (you *can* write events in a more manual way, if you need more control - but frankly: the inbuilt stuff is usually fine)

Comment: @MaxMichel it doesn't do anything "during" - it awaits *either* the timeout *xor* the signal - until one of those two things happen: it doesn't do anything, because there is nothing useful to do; note: you could also check the *correct* value is assigned in the `handler` code, if there's a chance it could be assigned multiple times and you need a specific value - i.e. `EventHandler handler = (s, a) => { if (/* check condition */) {cts.Cancel();}}`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Obvious mistake I didn't notice ! Apologies for that. The issue with the CancellationToken I feel is that I don't want to cancel the event as such but more stop the condition checking if it ever becomes false and then be ready for a new event.

Comment: @MaxMichel k, the context isn't 100% clear to me in the question; but: "here's a generic way to do a thing in an interruptible way, with a timeout, that observes external changes via events" - it should be possible to refactor to suit the specific scenario

Answer (score 0):

What I have found (That seems to work so far) is as Marc stated in his answer, "a bit hacky".

Here is my 'solution'. Please feel free to identify weaknesses and misconceptions.

```
Task.Run(async delegate
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    bool completed = true;
    while (stopwatch.Elapsed <= Configuration.ActiveDelay)
    {
        if (DerivedInstance.CurrentValue == SetpointA)
        {
            await Task.Delay(50); // Wait in ms
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not true anymore");
            completed = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(completed);
    EvaluateConditionDelayed();¨
}
```